# How does the punctuation used affect the meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, punctuation

Here is the sentence:

> **Life in Britain changed enormously under Elizabeth; but the
> monarchy adapted, and emerged stronger.**

Were it up to me, I would phrase it based on my comprehension as:

> **Life in Britain changed enormously under Elizabeth; the monarchy adapted and emerged stronger.**

But this is the Economist, and the author likely knows how to employ the punctuations to the greatest effect. I wonder if anyone could kindly explain to me **what the meaning based on how the semi-colon and the comma are used here is.**

And here is the original passage:

> After 70 years on the throne, Britain’s longest-reigning monarch died
> on September 8th, aged 96. Only Britons already in old age can
> remember singing “God Save the King” for George VI, but they will now
> do so for Elizabeth’s son and successor, Charles III. Life in Britain
> changed enormously under Elizabeth; but the monarchy adapted, and
> emerged stronger. On this page you will find our assessments of her
> reign and what the future might hold for Britain, the 14 other
> countries where Charles is now head of state and the wider
> Commonwealth.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it misleadingly claims to be about punctuation, when the significant aspect of the different texts is actually the inclusion / omission of contrastive conjunction ***but***

Comment: No claims made or misleading intended; if any, it was inadvertent. I was unsure how to phrase my enquiry to not be 'off-topic', as I am not a native speaker of English, let alone a linguistic expert. You could have answered this 'off-topic' question with your expertise, though.

Comment: The question was already answered by @Edwin and upvoted by me before I closevoted. Note that if the title *hadn't* misleadingly referred to punctuation, you'd simply have been asking whether the presence or absence of the word ***but*** makes any difference to your example. Which would have been immediately thrown out as "Too Basic" for this site, I'm sure.

Comment: I suppose I was fortunate to have been misleading enough to be perceived as sufficiently difficult to warrant an answer. It is rather patronising.

Comment: Nick: I'm still not clear exactly what you're asking here, but [Can you use a semi-colon before "but"?](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-use-a-semi-colon-before-but) was asked on Quora, where the first answer starts ***No,** because you use a semicolon to separate two independent clauses that are **not joined by a conjunction**.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the omitting of the 'but' that changes the meaning. The inclusion of 'but' indicates that the monarchy adapted *to cope with* the changes taking place in society at large. 'But' = 'but, though this was happening,'.

(The original semicolon before the 'but' is used, rather than the expected comma, to show that this is a more major separator than the comma used before 'and'. A 'supercomma' usage. Semicolons before coordinators are otherwise archaic.)

Without the 'but', the implication is that the monarchy adapting is merely part of (not necessarily in response to) the enormous changes in the country.

Comment: So to sum up: the former sentence basically says that there were changes during the reign, but the institution also adjusted itself to cope with these changes. The latter sentence would mean that there were changes and the monarchy adjusting itself was also a part of those changes. 

You have made it plain. Thank you very much!

Comment: The version without 'but' is ambiguous; 'as part of the overall change' is likely (or the causality should be specified), but causality ('in response to') isn't ruled out.